# Is it possible to view the constraints while using docplex?

Tags: python, cplex, docplex, quadratic-programming

I have a quadratic model which I wrote using docplex and when solving it says it is infeasible. When I checked to see if there are any conflicts it returned 0 so I assume there are none but I have no idea what is causing this problem. I want to be able to view the constraints like you can do in LINGO (CTRL+G). Also, is there any other way of solving a quadratic program using python with proper documentation to make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

have you also checked the relaxations ?
Have you tried to solve the same model but without the objective and then you will see that you have some issues with the objective ?

If the model is the same as the one you shared at [Why doesn't my CPLEX API solve the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580758/why-doesnt-my-cplex-api-solve-the-problem) have you tried to have a look at the relaxations ?

With CPLEX you may also try to use OPL for [quadratic models](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooquadratic.mod) which may be easier for debugging. There conflicts and relaxations will directly appear when your model is not feasible.

Comment: I have switched from CPLEX to Gurobi. CPLEX was giving very different values from the model I wrote in LINGO to check on. Gurobi API has worked with me and I managed to see the model in lp form. I might try and use CPLEX later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, within CPLEX you can also use OPL which is CPLEX Algebraic Modeling Language : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimization-aka-prescriptive-analytics-should-we-write-fleischer/